# Rename app in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to rename my app using code. The procedure is i give a name through my app and it should be my app name there after. I can change it again through my app. Can any one help? Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Rakesh Kiron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible once the app is installed on a device. Since the name is specified in the Info.plist and the Info.plist is in the bundle **and you can not write to the bundle once installed**, this is impossible.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1

Comment: Cant the Product Name in the infoplist be changed through code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854795/is-it-possible-to-write-new-file-to-bundle-resource-directory-in-ios-app

Comment: As I said, no. Since the name is specified in the Info.plist and the Info.plist is in the bundle and you can not write to the bundle once installed, this is impossible.